# How to give guest users "not logged in" a role?

Tags: users

I'm trying to give guest users "not logged in" a role.

I searched everywhere and I could not find a single solution that can make that happen. All what I found is to make an if statement in the `functions.php` file to give access to certain things, like for example post a comment without logging in.

However when there are a lot of roles it's hard to make it that way and it starts to be complicated.

Is there any way that I can achieve that?

Things that I have used

```
add_role( 'custom_role', 'Custom Role', array( 'read' => true ) );
```

and

```
 <?php
 global $user_login;
 if( $user_login ) {
    echo 'user logged in';
 } else {
    echo 'user not logged in';
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: So you want to rename the guest role? Or do you want to change the permissions the guest role has? Why do you want the guests to have another role? You could adjust the permissions for the existing role or just rename it to your needs.

Comment: I want to show somethıng to users who doesnt logın yet to my websıte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add to the template directly or via a short code from PHP Snippets plugin.

Source: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/

```
   <?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo 'Welcome, registered user!';
} else {
    echo 'Welcome, visitor!';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to show content to logged in users and not logged in users, you don't need to create new role for this. Wordpress will notice if a user is logged in, if you use the following function:

```
<?php
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo 'Welcome, registered user!';
    } else {
        echo 'Welcome, visitor!';
    }
?>
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/

So like you wrote in the comment, you want to show text if the user is not logged in. You can write in the template file of your theme (where you want the message to show, check out: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) an if statement. If the is_user_logged_in is not (using !) true, show the message:

```
<?php
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo "You are not logged in.";
    }
?>
```